# Apache with a self signed certificate displays wrong certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm trying to setup Apache to use a self signed certificate but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried many methods and last tried [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/17061/generate-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache) but still ran into the same issue. Safari (And Chrome) give me a completely different certificate (Not even close to the one I provide it) that makes no sense at all. I haven't heard of anyone else having this issue nor do I know where it's getting "ORname_Jungo: OpenRG Products Group" from. I also posted my ssl configuration [here](http://pastebin.com/9vmvpyZv).

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Here's]

Comment: How did you generate the certificate?

Comment: I generated it with `openssl req -new -x509 -days 999 -nodes -out apache.pem -keyout apache.pem`

Comment: where id apache come from? what OS / distro?  Do you use http://www.jungo.com/openrg/pr_openrg.html?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what caused this. First off the "server" is a test machine I'm running within my home network that I use to test things before pushing them to the real server. I realized that I had forgotten to forward port 443 for https, thus sending the request to my router, not my server so it was returning my routers ssl certificate (Which I was unaware it even had). After forwarding the port all is working.